# Is there a name for these numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology

Is there a name for a number whose sum of the proper divisors, *excluding* $1$ (so, **not** a perfect number), is equal to the original number?

Googling is of no help.

Comment: Including 1 are called perfect numbers.

Comment: See [perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number).

Comment: I don't think there are any special name for the set of perfect numbers excluding $1$. And I don't see a reason why there should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a name. Numbers $n \in \mathbf N$ with your property have 
$$ \sigma(n) = 2n + 1 $$
($\sigma$ denoting the *sum of divisors*-function). Such numbers are called *quasiperfect numbers*, see for example on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiperfect_number). There is no known example of such a number.

Comment: Why define a class of numbers having no known elements?!